# Fullscreen HTML API to work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, fullscreen

I am trying to force a video to go to full screen (native)  when a specific button is clicked on. I am using the fullscreen html API for this, and in Opera/Chrome it works like its supposed to. In Firefox however it does not. Whenever I click my button and call my JS it just forces the browser itself to go to fullscreen (just like when you press F11 on your keyboard). I have the following code:

Video:

HTML:

```
<video id="videoTrailer" controls src="I removed the video link here"></video>
```

CSS:

```
#videoTrailer{
display: none;
}
```

Im just placing my video anywhere in my html doc and hide it.

Button:

```
    <div id="trailerButton" class="btn col-3" onClick="showTrailer()">my trailer text
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}

#trailerButton{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
border: 2px solid yellow;
border-bottom: none;
bottom:0;
border-top-right-radius:1em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
padding-bottom: 0.3em;
padding-top: 0.3em;
padding-right: 0em;
padding-left: 0em;
}

#trailerButton:hover{
    color:yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var pauseTrailer = function () {
'use strict';
var elem = document.getElementById("videoTrailer");
elem.pause();
};

var showTrailer = function () {
    'use strict';
    var elem = document.getElementById("videoTrailer");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", pauseTrailer);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", pauseTrailer);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", pauseTrailer);
document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", pauseTrailer);
};
```

So what I am basically looking for is a pure Javascript solution that makes my video go to fullscreen (native) in Firefox (im not allowed to use jQuery for this) I would like to point out though that my javascript knowledge is limited. Thanks in advance.